# Changing :before sign when slidedown Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, menuitem

I have navbar from bootstrap in sidebar and I want to change :before sign on click on element in my menu. But I have problem... It's looks like:

[image]

But I want to change "+" sign to "-" after click. It should looks like it: 
[image]

This menu have 2depth. U can see it how it works on [port.cruzzapps.com](https://port.cruzzapps.com)

It's my JS, but this code not working propely:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".collapse li a").click(function(event){
       $('.collapse li a').removeClass();
       $(this).addClass('minus');
       event.preventDefault();

  });
```

});

Comment: What is the class that you want to remove? `collapse`?

Comment: I want to change "+" when click link and open menu. Now it works but it change everywhere..
If u can see this menu working on page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li a").click(function(event){
       $(this).toggleClass('collapse');
       $(this).toggleClass('minus');
       event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I'm using `toggleClass` so that way when you click it again, the original class is added back and the new class is removed. What this code does is when an anchor tag in a list is clicked, it loses it's `collapse` class and gains a `minus` class. When it is clicked again, it loses it's `minus` class and gains the `collapse` class. If you've set up your CSS properly this will give you the effect you want.

Note I also changed your selector inside the `click` handler to not select every `.collapse li a` as that was changing all of the elements rather than just the one you wanted.

Comment: Great, it works :) I need only few changes in my css :) THANKS!